# Run / Close Programs over and over again

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

Is there a way I can write a simple script to run a program, close that program about 5 seconds later, and then repeat?

I just want to be able to run a program that I wrote over and over again but to do so Id have to close it like 5 seconds after running it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### If your command is *non-interactive* (requires no user interaction):

Launch your program in the *background* with control operator `&`, which gives you access to its PID (process ID) via `$!`, by which you can kill the running program instance after sleeping for 5 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start an infinite loop.
# Use ^C to abort.
while :; do

  # Launch the program in the background.
  /path/to/your/program &

  # Wait 5 seconds, then kill the program (if still alive).
  sleep 5 && { kill $! && wait $!; } 2>/dev/null

done
```

---

#### If your command is *interactive*:

More work is needed if your command must run in the foreground to allow user interaction: then it is the command to kill the program after 5 seconds that must run in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Turn on job control, so we can bring a background job back to the
# foreground with `fg`.
set -m

# Start an infinite loop.
# CAVEAT: The only way to exit this loop is to kill the current shell.
#         Setting up an INT (^C) trap doesn't help.
while :; do

  # Launch program in background *initially*, so we can reliably
  # determine its PID.
  # Note: The command line being set to the bakground is invariably printed 
  #       to stderr. I don't know how to suppress it (the usual tricks
  #       involving subshells and group commands do not work).
  /path/to/your/program &
  pid=$!   # Save the PID of the background job.

  # Launch the kill-after-5-seconds command in the background.
  # Note: A status message is invariably printed to stderr when the
  #       command is killed. I don't know how to suppress it (the usual tricks
  #       involving subshells and group commands do not work).
  { (sleep 5 && kill $pid &) } 2>/dev/null 

  # Bring the program back to the foreground, where you can interact with it.
  # Execution blocks until the program terminates - whether by itself or
  # by the background kill command.
  fg

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the watch command. It will let you run a program repeatedly monitoring the output. Might have to get a little fancy if you need to kill that program manually after 5 seconds.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch

A simple example:

```
watch -n 5 foo.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

To literally answer your question:

Run 10 times with sleep 5:

```
#!/bin/bash 
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
    # your script
    sleep 5
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done
```

Run continuously:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while [ 1 ]; do
    # your script
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no input on the code, you can simply do

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
    ./exec_name

    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```